# Problemas al visualizar datos con matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente dataframe con los siguientes datos de algunos iPhone:

```
Dispositivo  Año_lanzamiento  Precio_$  Precio_€ Categoría
0            iPhone 8           2017.0     699.0     809.0      Base
1            iPhone X           2017.0     999.0    1159.0       Pro
2           iPhone XR           2018.0     749.0     859.0      Base
3           iPhone XS           2018.0     999.0    1159.0       Pro
4       iPhone XS Max           2018.0    1099.0    1259.0   Pro Max
5           iPhone 11           2019.0     699.0     809.0      Base
6       iPhone 11 Pro           2019.0     999.0    1159.0       Pro
7   iPhone 11 Pro Max           2019.0    1099.0    1259.0   Pro Max
8           iPhone 12           2020.0     799.0     909.0      Base
9       iphone 12 Pro           2020.0     999.0    1159.0       Pro
10  iPhone 12 Pro Max           2020.0    1099.0    1259.0   Pro Max
11          iPhone 13           2021.0     799.0     909.0      Base
12      iPhone 13 Pro           2021.0     999.0    1159.0       Pro
13  iPhone 13 Pro Max           2021.0    1099.0    1259.0   Pro Max
14          iPhone 14           2022.0     799.0    1009.0     Base 
15     iPhone 14 Pro            2022.0     999.0    1319.0       Pro
16  iPhone 14 Pro Max           2022.0    1099.0    1469.0   Pro Max
```

He estado intentando graficar los datos y si por ejemplo selecciono los modelos Pro se me visualiza todo correctamente:

```
# Filtra el DataFrame para seleccionar solo los dispositivos de la categoría "Pro"
df_base = df[df['Categoría'] == 'Pro']

# Selecciona las columnas que quieres graficar
x = df_base['Año_lanzamiento']
y = df_base['Precio_€']

# Crea el gráfico
plt.plot(x, y, color = "red", marker = "o", linestyle = "-", linewidth = 2, markersize = 5)

# Agrega etiquetas a los ejes
plt.xlabel('Año de lanzamiento')
plt.ylabel('Precio en euros')

plt.title('Evolución del precio de los iPhone Pro', color = '#381f22')

# Muestra el gráfico
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego si selecciono por ejemplo los modelos base no entiendo porque me salen años terminados en .5 y quería eliminar eso

```
# Filtra el DataFrame para seleccionar solo los dispositivos de la categoría "Base"
df_base = df[df['Categoría'] == 'Base']

# Selecciona las columnas que quieres graficar
x = df_base['Año_lanzamiento']
y = df_base['Precio_€']

# Crea el gráfico
plt.plot(x, y, color = "red", marker = "o", linestyle = "-", linewidth = 2, markersize = 5)

# Agrega etiquetas a los ejes
plt.xlabel('Año de lanzamiento')
plt.ylabel('Precio en euros')

plt.title('Evolución del precio de los iPhone Base', color = '#381f22')

# Muestra el gráfico
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Eso es por que tienes el año como entero (`int`), debería ser un `datetime`

Comment: No, los tiene como `float` prueba justamente convertirlos en un `int`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar de ninguna forma

Answer (score 0):

En el dataframe salen como float, los puedes cambiar con el siguiente codigo a int.

```
    # Cambiar las columnas de tipo float a tipo int
    df['Año_lanzamiento'] = df['Año_lanzamiento'].astype(int)
    df['Precio_$'] = df['Precio_$'].astype(int)
    df['Precio_€'] = df['Precio_€'].astype(int)
```

Comment: ¿Por que conviertes los precios en un entero si en todo caso el problema está con el año?

Comment: los datos de los años estan en formato float y los gráficos de lineas son para parámetros continuos. y como matplotlib genera automaticamente los valores del eje x. para hcer el arreglo de forma automatica debes ocupar la función 'plt.xticks()'

Comment: agrega al codigo antes de plt.show() lo siguiente:     plt.xticks(x.astype(int))